# Count number of records for a given day

Tags: python, sql, pandas, date, count

I used to have a SQL query to count number of records for a given day, in a given location.

Input Data structure was like this :
id, location, start_date, end_date

```
import pandas as pd
data = [('20170009003','0681','2017-07-25','2017-08-02'),
('20170009221','0682','2017-07-28','2017-08-02'),
('20170009271','0682','2017-07-31','2017-08-02'),
('20170009286','0681','2017-07-18','2017-09-19'),
('20170009654','0682','2017-07-28','2017-08-03'),
('20170010053','0681','2017-07-31','2017-08-04'),
('20170010059','0681','2017-07-20','2017-08-07')]
labels = ['idnum','loc','start_date','end_date']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=labels)
```

This would give me the count of (present) persons on a given day. i.e. the '2018-08-01', would get:

```
2018-08-01, 0681, 4
2018-08-01, 0682, 3
```

I'd like to produce a similar result with python/pandas.

If it's of any help, the sql (postgreql function) used to achieve the above goal was :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION nb_present(oneday date)
 RETURNS TABLE(ddj date, loc character, eff numeric)
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
SELECT $1, loc,sum(case when ($1= start_date and start_date_end_date) then 1 
                when $1=start_date then 0.5 
                when $1=end_date then 0.5 
                when ($1 > start_date and $1 < end_date) then 1 
                else 0 end)
from passage group by 1,2 order by 1,2;
$function$
```

Thanks for your help.

PS: This is my first post here.

Comment: what have you tried so far? by the way your english is perfect. nothing to worry :-)

Comment: can you provide your sample data in a different format? no vertical lines for example

Comment: //number of present persons a given day, ie the '2018-08-01'//  Are you sure you meant `2018-08-01` and not `2017-08-01`?

Comment: @Yuca: I edited the data

Comment: @Vishnu, sure, it's a mistake, i meant 2017

Comment: are your dates strings?

Comment: Yes, my date where strings converted to date with the following : pd.to_datetime(df['end_date'], yearfirst=True).dt.date (I read my data from a csv) but it doesn't seem a good idea

Comment: ok, my code works if dates are strings

Comment: Do you only want a method that incorporates Pandas or would a pure python method be okay?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you're looking for (make sure your `startdate` and `enddate` are pandas `Datetime` objects):

```
dt = pd.to_datetime('2018-08-01')
df1 = df[(df['startdate'] > dt) & (df['enddate'] < dt)].groupby('loc').count().to_frame()
df1['Date'] = dt
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
target = '2017-08-01'
df[(df['start_date'] < target) & (df['end_date'] > target)].groupby(['loc']).size()
```

Output:

```
  loc
0681    4
0682    3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution if you want to do this frequently for several dates:
We create another `DataFrame` that checks whether that row is between the start and end dates (using an `IntervalIndex`, but not necessary). We can then group that `DataFrame` by the `loc` variable in the other `DataFrame` (grouping is aligned on index, so we use `.reset_index` to ensure everything is aligned with our newly created `DataFrame`) and just take a sum, since we have `True` or `False`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.start_date)
df['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.end_date)
df.index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df.start_date, df.end_date, closed='both')

# Dates you care about
dates = pd.to_datetime(['2017-08-01', '2017-08-02', '2017-08-03'])

df_bet = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape([d in ids for d in dates for ids in df.index] ,(-1, len(df))), index=dates).T

df_bet.groupby(df.reset_index()['loc']).agg(sum)
```

## Output:

```
      2017-08-01  2017-08-02  2017-08-03
loc                                     
0681         4.0         4.0         3.0
0682         3.0         3.0         1.0
```

Comment: @Yuca It would be even nicer if you could slice a `datetime` IntervalIndex by date like you can normal intervals, but that doesn't seem to work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

With your help, i came with :

```
import pandas as pd
data = [('20170009003','0681','2017-07-25','2017-08-02'),
('20170009221','0682','2017-07-28','2017-08-02'),
('20170009271','0682','2017-07-31','2017-08-02'),
('20170009286','0681','2017-07-18','2017-09-19'),
('20170009654','0682','2017-07-28','2017-08-03'),
('20170010053','0681','2017-07-31','2017-08-04'),
('20170010059','0681','2017-07-20','2017-08-07')]
labels = ['idnum','loc','start_date','end_date']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=labels)
df['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_date'])
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'])
dt = pd.to_datetime('2017-08-01')
df1 = df[(df['start_date'] < dt) & (df['end_date'] > dt)].groupby('loc').size().to_frame()
df1['Date'] = dt
```

Which works fine.

Now,  I have to tweak it to count the number of present for each day between two dates. I'll keep that as homework.

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you need to do it for all dates between a range, I suggest you look at my solution. You simply need to provide the dates in a list, which can be accomplished with `pd.date_range('start_day', 'end_day', freq='d')`; just fill in the dates.

Answer (score 0):

Using just python this is possible, using sorted with two elements and groupby with two elements

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

data = sorted(data, key= itemgetter(-1, 1))
for k, g in groupby(data, key = itemgetter(-1, 1)):
    print('{}, {}, {}'.format(k[0], k[1], len(list(g))))
```

> ```
> 2017-08-02, 0681, 1
> 2017-08-02, 0682, 2
> 2017-08-03, 0682, 1
> 2017-08-04, 0681, 1
> 2017-08-07, 0681, 1
> 2017-09-19, 0681, 1
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I finally came up with a sligthly different solution. As I needed to merge the resulting dataframe with another one, here is what I did:

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame()
for dt in pd.date_range('2017-08-01', '2017-08-05'):
    df1 = df[(df['start_date'] < dt) & (df['end_date'] > dt)].groupby('loc').size().to_frame().reset_index()
    df1['Date'] = dt
    df0 = df0.append(df1)
```

Best regards